# How do I escape windows repair install and start in normal boot?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, repair

I have a corrupted file in the OS (running a poweredge t410, windows server 2003 RT). Booting up in safe mode shows it stopped at acpitabl.dat. Google results led me to believe that the update.sys file was corrupted. So I tried to load it on the disk, but I was having trouble: "unable to create file update.sys 0 files expanded"

So instead of going into recovery console from the installation disk, I entered "install windows" ... where It would detect the previous installation and repair it.

As I did that, I realized that I wasn't using the original installation disk (for licensing reasons, one is standard edition the other is R2), when I switch out the disk I receive a signature error.

When I try to access the recovery console now, it no longer asks me for the administrator password, which means I can't write files on the disk. However I can read them. When I try to boot up without the disk, it leads me the Windows Repair Installation window and then asks for the disk.

Is there anyway out of this, or did I dig myself a hole?

**TLDR;** I forced a windows OS installation repair due to a corrupt file in the OS, I want to escape the repair installation ( e.g. http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/5/H/0/-/-/xpnew10.jpg)

Comment: Files don't just corrupt themselves. You should get a new HD and start over. You can move the old one and use it as a second drive if there is important information you want to pull from it.

Comment: It was a sudden-power loss and the UPS lost power as well. This server was on a RAID 1, one of the drives failed. I'm assuming that when this happened the file became corrupted?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've dug yourself into a hole. Since you *started* the installation, it overwrote *some* of the files and now you've got a completely corrupted Windows installation on your hands. But like Mark Ransom says, disk corruption is a serious thing. You need to do a complete reinstall/restore to ensure the integrity of your system anyway. If the data is salvageable, consider yourself lucky.